# Add delimiter for best_in_place gem for rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i would like to add a pipe delimter for saving a field, iam gonna add strings seperated by commas, while saving to db, replace all commas with pipe, mongodb is used for backend, anyideas?

Comment: This question isn't really about MongoDB. You have to transform data as required in your Ruby code before passing it to the database to be saved. It sounds like you want something as simple as a search & replace (eg. [String `gsub()` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)).